# How to open another view controller when OK is pressed in alert.addAction in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display a viewcontroller called InViewController, when the "OK" from the `add.alertAction` is pressed.

```
if ((user) != nil) {               
   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message:   "Logged In", preferredStyle: .Alert)
   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
   self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Logged In", preferredStyle: .Alert)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) -> Void in
  let viewControllerYouWantToPresent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SomeViewControllerIdentifier")
  self.presentViewController(viewControllerYouWantToPresent!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
alert.addAction(action)
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: how do you want to instantiate the controller that should be opened? from the storyboard? did you give it an identifier? i do not mean its class but a storyboard identifier! cause this is what you have to put in here...

Comment: I changed it to the the identifier of the segue i had set to the view controller i want to present, but it still terminates saying there's no such identifier. Sorry for the last question, man, I'm a hardcore beginner and also half a moron.

Comment: if you have set up a segue instead of `let viewControllerYouWant...` and `self.presentViewController...` you can simply call `self.performSegueWithIdentifier` and pass your segues identifier!

Comment: I got is, man, i assigned the identifier and it all worked. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 3):

You can add a completionHandler to the `UIAlertAction` when you add it to do it what you want, like in the following way:

```
if ((user) != nil) {               
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message:   "Logged In", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { _ -> Void in 
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerA") as! ViewControllerA
        self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })

    alert.addAction(OKAction)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
}
```

To set the `StoryboardID` you can use Interface Builder in the **Identity Inspector**, see the following picture:

[image]

I put everything in the above code referencing `ViewControllerA`, you have to set the name of your `UIViewController` according what you want.

**EDIT**:

You are pointing to a `UIView` or some other object on the StoryBoard. Press the yellow indicator on top of the other objects which is your `UIViewController`, like in the following picture:

[image]

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. I get an error, however when i put in the name of the view controller i want

Comment: Sorry , but you need to put here an instance of an `UIViewController`, see updated answer for more information

Comment: I only have Restoration ID under my Identity Inspector. Do you know where else would I be able to set that Storyboard ID?

Comment: You need to mark first your viewcontroller in the Storyboard

Comment: Don't worry, but it's strange it's up the `Restoration ID`, are you sure?

Comment: Got it,dude! I changed the identifier, the code, however gave an error. I just used the code from andre slotta and your instructions and the bitch fell right asleep. I appreciate the time you took to explain everything so a moron such as myself could understand

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do that , 
I'm just updating the good work of Victor Sigler

you follow his answer with this little update ..

```
 private func alertUser( alertTitle title: String, alertMessage  message: String )
{
   let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message,   preferredStyle: .alert)
    let actionTaken = UIAlertAction(title: "Success", style: .default) { (hand) in
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let destinationVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IntroPage") as? StarterViewController
        self.present(destinationVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    alert.addAction(actionTaken)
    self.present(alert, animated: true) {}
}
```